# Combinatoric problem

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Let $2\leq k\leq r\leq n$ are positive integers and $r=kt$.
I construct sets  such that $\cup_{i=1}^n A_i=\{1,2,3,\dots,n\}=X$, this union is disjoint and if $x\in A_i$ and $y\in A_j$ for all $i\leq j$, then  $x<y$. I put one condition such that any $t$ sets will contain $k$ elements and the others will be single elements. How can I count the number of such sets?

Example: Let $n=8$, $r=6$, $k=2$ and since $r=kt$, $6=23$, $t=3$.
then
We can spilts $9$ different ways with above conditions as in the following:
$$1=\{A_1=\{1,2\},A_2=\{3,4\},A_3=\{5,6\},A_4=\{7\},A_5=\{8\}\}$$
$$2=\{A_1=\{1,2\},A_2=\{3,4\},A_3=\{5\},A_4=\{6,7\},A_5=\{8\}\}$$
$$3=\{A_1=\{1,2\},A_2=\{3,4\},A_3=\{5\},A_4=\{6\},A_5=\{7,8\}\}$$
$$4=\{A_1=\{1,2\},A_2=\{3\},A_3=\{4,5\},A_4=\{6,7\},A_5=\{8\}\}$$
$$5=\{A_1=\{1,2\},A_2=\{3\},A_3=\{4,5\},A_4=\{6\},A_5=\{7,8\}\}$$
$$6=\{A_1=\{1,2\},A_2=\{3\},A_3=\{4\},A_4=\{5,6\},A_5=\{7,8\}\}$$
$$7=\{A_1=\{1\},A_2=\{2,3\},A_3=\{4,5\},A_4=\{6,7\},A_5=\{8\}\}$$
$$8=\{A_1=\{1\},A_2=\{2,3\},A_3=\{4,5\},A_4=\{6\},A_5=\{7,8\}\}$$
$$9=\{A_1=\{1\},A_2=\{2,3\},A_3=\{4\},A_4=\{5,6\},A_5=\{7,8\}\}.$$

Comment: Are you missing a 10th arrangement in your example? Where $A_1=\{1\}$ and $A_2=\{2\}$?

Comment: Yes you are right. Answer is $10$.

Comment: Cross-posted and answered on MO [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/373834/combinatoric-problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A valid split will have $t$ blocks of $k$ consecutive integers and $n-kt$ singletons; for convenience let $m=n-kt$. Then a valid split is completely described by a $(t+m)$-bit string with $t$ ones and $m$ zeroes, in which a $1$ bit represents a block of length $k$, and a $0$ bit represents a singleton. In the example in the question, for instance, the first two splits listed are represented by the strings $11100$ and $11010$, respectively. Clearly there are $\binom{t+m}t=\binom{t+m}m$ such strings and hence the same number of valid splits.